# Administrar subdominios desde api

Tags: api, email, dominio, cloud, subdominio

Me interesa saber cuál servicio me recomiendan donde me permita administrar mis dominios y correos asociados a esos dominios desde una api, o sea, yo quiero crear subdominios y direcciones de correos tipo no-reply para mis clientes de modo dinámico desde mi app, ejemplo crear para mis clientes de modo dinámico [**ProyectoDelCliente**].[**UsuarioDelCliente**].miapp.com y no-reply@[**ProyectoDelCliente**].[**UsuarioDelCliente**].miapp.com o [**ProyectoDelCliente**]@[**UsuarioDelCliente**].miapp.com
Un buen servicio cloud que me permita administrar, crear, hacer eso desde una API. Y el correo no-reply que le daría a mis clientes sería como es lógico para enviar emails personalizados de ellos, sin bandeja de entrada.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], para que comprendas mejor cómo funciona el sitio. Tu pregunta pide recomendaciones de recursos externos, lo cual es motivo de cierre, porque aquí no hacemos recomendaciones de ese tipo. Las preguntas válidas son aquellas que buscan resolver un problema de programación específico o concreto, que se pueda reproducir. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.